# PHP Yii framework error message Undefined index

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to give allowed extension so I did try this code but I get error say

Undefined index: files[]

```
  $ly_formname = 'files[]';

    $file_type = $_FILES[$ly_formname]['type']; //returns the mimetype

    $allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "application/pdf");
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
      $error_message = 'Only jpg, gif, and pdf files are allowed.';
      $error = 'yes';
    }
```

I changed my variable name and still get the message error

the form name is file[] in yii framework

```
public function run()
    {
        return Html::input('file', 'files[]', null, $this->getOptions());
    }
```

the input code I have is :

```
<input type="file" id="contentFormFilesGallery" name="files[]"
 multiple="multiple" title="Upload file" accept="image/*" data-upload-url="" 
data-upload-drop-zone="#contentFormBody" data-upload-
progress="#contentFormFiles_progress" data-upload-
preview="#contentFormFiles_preview" data-upload-form="" data-upload-single="" 
data-upload-submit-name="fileList[]" data-upload-hide-in-stream="" data-php-max-
file-uploads="20" data-php-max-file-uploads-message="Sorry, you can only upload 
up to 20 files at once." data-max-number-of-files="50" data-max-number-of-files-
message="This upload field only allows a maximum of 50 files." data-ui-
widget="file.Upload" data-ui-init="1" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `files[]` to `files`.
By having multiple form elements with the same name, PHP will convert those to an array. You don't have to (and can't) treat them as an array in HTML.

So, if you have two input with the name `files`, you can access it as `$_POST['files']` or `$_GET['files']`.